# Atom text editor - background under text darker than page background

Tags: atom-editor

For the life of me, I can't figure this one out.

On a fresh install of atom, any dark syntax theme I add has the area under the text darker than the rest of the page.  To make this situation more distracting this effect flickers off/on on the first hover over a tab.

I forgot the technical details. I have an early 2015 MBP with a fresh OS X Sierra install.

[image]

Comment: Odd, is that just this theme?  what happens when you switch to a light theme?  Do you happen to get a very pale yellow as the background in parts or not?

Comment: @Matt, I do get the same effect on light themes but its very faint, maybe 1% difference. AtomLight is the only syntax theme that doesn't seem to do this.

Comment: Any updates? I'm having this one too

Answer (score 1):

Preferences -> Under Core tab -> color profile ->change to Use sRGB

[image: check the link below]

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem & after reading [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Atom/comments/56mzqw/annoying_ui_problem_i_cant_figure_out_text_has/) reddit thread, I switched between my colour profiles a bit and found one which solved the issue for me.

[image: System Preferences > Displays > Color]